# Is it possible to use socket.io without node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The title pretty muchs sums it up... I am wondering if there is a way to  use socket.io without node.js

Comment: Wrong question: what are you trying to do? Because maybe socket.io isn't even the right tool for the job and standard websockets without the 1.5Mb of socket.io on top is plenty.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Is your server using a language other than Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io is a library that connects a browser web pages to some server somewhere.  There MUST be a socket.io server somewhere that does what you want that you can connect to.

That socket.io server does not have to be written using node.js.  There is socket.io support for other languages or environments.  The protocol and data format is fully documented so implementations can be written for any environment. 
For example, here's a [socket.io server implementation in C++](https://github.com/mrudangit/Socket.IO.Server.CPP).

You can look on github for various server implementations: https://github.com/search?q=socket.io+server.

Comment: I think you should add github's search result for "socket.io server" because it's useful to find one for your language: https://github.com/search?q=socket.io+server

Comment: Also, the protocol is fully documented in https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol and https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol so in theory you can implement a server yourself in any language